# Add and subtract times in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a vacation/absence list that contains two fields:

1. `fromDate` (Date and Time type);
2. `toDate` (Date and Time type).

In addition to date difference, I want to calculate the time differences between these dates and put it into another field `total` that contains only time.

I also want to update the `total` field after a new item added, and also often show the `total` to user in `hh:mm` format.

How can I add to or subtract from the time in `total` field?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a new field of type calculated field? A calculated field enables you to define its value through a formula.

Please provides further details on what you've already tried.

Comment: I have tried but how can I put the time differences in to total for every item added? I mean total must be update for every item

Answer (score 0):

Add calculated field "Total" to your list and put the following formula in there:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(HOUR([EndTime]-[StartTime]),"#"),":",TEXT(MINUTE([EndTime]-[StartTime]), "#"))
```

This only works within the same day by the way.